# Как вывести в Delphi в Label число с плавающей точкой?

Tags: delphi

Как в Delphi в Label вывести значение числа с плавающей точкой? При чем, если у числе нет знаков после запятой, то после запятой должно стоять два нуля. Например:
Значение     Вывод
10           10.00
10,34234     10,34
Как это сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте функцию [FloatToStrF](http://delphibasics.ru/FloatToStrF.php)

Comment: а не подскажете синтаксис?

Answer (score 1):

(f:extended)

```
f:=123.456789;
Label1.Caption:=FloatToStrF(f, ffGeneral, 10, 2);
```

или

```
Label1.Caption:=format('%10.2f',[f]);
```